# SQL Server changes characters in insert

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server changes same characters in the Strings.

Example:

```
insert into TEST_TABLE
values ('árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép2');
```

inserts

```
árvízturo tükörfúrógép
```

The `TEST_TABLE` has only one column with type `varchar(50)`.

How can I insert strings into a table in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will most likely need an `nvarchar` (rather than `varchar`) data type on the column that allows unicode characters.

You will probably need to specify it being unicode too by prefixing the value with an "N".

```
insert into TEST_TABLE
values (N'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the column `datatype` to `nvarchar` and try this:

```
insert into TEST_TABLE
values (N'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code on your table:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ALTER COLUMN *ColumnName* nvarchar(50)
```

After that, it works like a charm (even without prefixing the inserting string with *N*).